# Swift Binary Search Falling Through to last return statement

Tags: swift

I am trying to implement binary search in Swift 4. The code seems to work, except that the code is falling through to the last return statement. I tried putting it in an `else` clause but get a compiler warning saying that control reaches end of non-void. I want it so if the conditions are met, that the code will return early and not exit with the -1 value of the last return statement.

```
let numbersArray:[Int] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 20]

var first: Int = 0
var last: Int = numbersArray.count - 1

func binarySearch(array: [Int], number: Int) -> Int{

    if array.count == 0 {return -1}
    else if array.count == 1{
            if array[0] == number {return array[0]}

            else {return -1}
    }

    let arrayMiddle: Int = array.count / 2

    if number == array[arrayMiddle] {return array[arrayMiddle]}

    else if number > array[arrayMiddle]{
           first = arrayMiddle + 1
            print("first in number > middle \(first)")
           last = array.count - 1
            print("last in number > middle \(last)")
            let slice: [Int] = Array(array[first...last])
            binarySearch(array: slice, number: number)


    }
    else if number < array[arrayMiddle]{
            last = arrayMiddle - 1
            print("last in number < middle \(last)")
            first = 0
            print("first in number < middle \(first)")
            let slice: [Int] = Array(array[first...last])
            binarySearch(array: slice, number: number)
    }

    print("got to last case")
    return -1
}
```

Comment: add `return` in front of `binarySearch(array: slice, number: number)`

Comment: why? the `return` is handled in this section `if array.count == 0 {return -1}
    else if array.count == 1{
            if array[0] == number {return array[0]}

            else {return -1}
    }`

Comment: Assume you call the 1st `binarySearch`, which call the 2nd `binarySearch`, which `return array[0]`. Since the 1st `binarySearch` does not return the 2nd `binarySearch`, the `array[0]` returned by the 2nd `binarySearch`  end up discarded (As you can see in your code, the result of `binarySearch` is not assigned to any variable nor returned). You have to `return binarySearch` so that the 1st `binarySearch` can return the result returned by the 2nd `binarySearch`

Comment: @RickyMo got it thanks. The playground did show the correct value before it passed through to the final return, so that was a little weird. Code works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

You're recursively calling `binarySearch` without returning the result, twice.

Comment: So basically, by returning the recursive function, what I'm saying is that I'm returning the value of that function call, therefore performing an early return?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `switch` and test against your 3 cases:

1. The value is after the middle. Create a slice after the middle and recursively call into that slice, returning the result of that call.
2. The value is the middle, return the middle index.
3. The value is before the middle. Create a slice before the middle and recursively call into that slice, returning the result of that call.

Also, I would make this generic and an extension on `RandomAccessCollection`. That way you don't need to turn each `ArraySlice` into an `Array` when you call the recursion. The other advantage is that `ArraySlice` maintains the indices of the original collection so you won’t need to maintain them yourself. By creating new `Array` instances you’re throwing that away.

Lastly, instead of returning a -1 you might want to use an `Optional` and return `nil` to indicate that the value is not in the collection. That's a fairly standard way to handle it.

My implementation:

```
extension RandomAccessCollection {
  func binarySearch<T>(value: T) -> Self.Index? where
    T: Comparable, Self.Element == T {
      guard !self.isEmpty else { return nil }

      let middle = self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: self.count / 2)

      switch self[middle] {
      case ..<value:
        let next = self.index(after: middle)
        return self[next...].binarySearch(value: value)
      case value:
        return middle
      default:
        return self[..<middle].binarySearch(value: value)
      }
  }
}
```